# How to use viewForZoomingInScrollView with simplified fake view in UIScrollView?

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I've looked all around the internets but could not find an example where viewForZoomingInScrollView returns a simplified fake view for zooming.

The reason I'm asking is that the zoom stutters when zooming out my huge retina-sized UIImageView with 3072x4096 pixels.

How does the view returned in viewForZoomingInScrollView need to be sized and positioned? Does it need to be inside the UIScrollView? Do I need to to remove the real view from the UIScrollView. I played around with different things now and failed.

Or is this actually not the intended way to use it?

Thank you.

Some more background: I'm using multiple sublayers inside the UIImageView, however when zooming only one should be visible. Also, I tried setting shouldRasterize while zooming, that did not help (much if at all).

Comment: Your question seems not be clear..give more details

Comment: could you please explain briefly with some code fragments

Comment: Question is not clear. Please add more details.